# What is known about representations of $S_n$ in other categories?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, symmetric-groups

Is anything known about representations of the symmetric group $S_n$ for categories other than $\textbf{Vect}_k$, vector spaces and linear maps over a field $k$.

That is, a group $G$ can be considered as a category with a single object in which morphisms are labeled by $g \in G$ and composition is given by the group law. Representations are functors $F:G\rightarrow \mathcal C$ for some other category $\mathcal C$.

Comment: I'd assume the case $\mathcal{C} = \underline{\textbf{Sets}}$ is pretty well understood too ;)

Comment: This is much too general. Are there particular categories you're interested in?

Comment: All you're asking is for objects $X$ of categories equipped with homomorphisms $S_n \rightarrow \text{Aut}(X)$.  This is such a tiny amount of structure that there is nothing you can say in general.

Comment: I'm aware of $\textbf{Set}$ and I didn't mean all categories, I'm just wondering if there's a specific one for which a theory is particularly well-developed, on the level of classical rep'n theory. I'm just looking for a generalization of the Fourier transform for non-abelian groups. How about $\textbf{Top}$, or just finite dim'l CW complexes?

Comment: Because every complex representation of a finite group is equivalent to a unitary representation, one could add the category of Hilbert spaces to the list in the question.

Comment: @JacksonWalters: For TOP, these are literally just spaces equipped with actions of the symmetric group.  That’s so general that you can’t say anything.  The same with finite CW complexes.

Comment: @WillChen I'm not sure what you mean by this. Every action of $S_n$ on a set decomposes as a disjoint union of orbits, but then orbits are in 1-1 correspondence with conjugation class of subgroups of $S_n$... So that's pretty much the same as classifying finite groups.

Comment: Perhaps a better direction to go is just $R$-modules. Rep’ns are equivalent to $k[S_n]$-modules, so one could study $R[S_n]$-modules. I know the story is already pretty complicated for fields of positive characteristic.

Comment: Every $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$-module decomposes as a direct sum of irreducible Specht modules which have matrix coefficients defined over the integers. So the representation theory of $\mathbb{R}[S_n]$ is essentially the same as that of $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$, at least until you start restricting to the alternating group, or smaller subgroups with non-real characters.

Comment: @MarkWildon I meant for a ring $R$, not $\mathbb{R}$. I’m not particularly interested in $\textbf{Vect}_k$ for fields $k$.

Comment: @JacksonWalters: Well then you get into the modular representation theory of $S_n$, right? This is also heavily studied.

Comment: @SamHopkins I thought modular rep’n theory only studied fields like $\mathbb{F}_p$ or positive characteristic fields $k$, so we’re still in $\textbf{Vect}_k$. Again, I was just curious if there is a more general setting where there is a notion of Fourier transform for nonabelian groups.

Comment: People study representations of groups over Dedekind domains (like the integers).  It's called integral representations.  Like modular representation theory things again get complicated

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I see, thank you. It sounds like things get tough even as we vary $R$ in $R$-Mod away from $\mathbb{C}$. I'm thinking about the hidden subgroup problem and wondering whether generalizing would help, but that's a separate question.